# How to 'undraw' an Image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, draw

I am trying to make a simple game in Java, All i need to do is draw an im onto the screen and then wait for 5 seconds then 'undraw it'.

Code (this class draws the image on the screen):

```
 package com.mainwindow.draw;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 import javax.swing.Timer;
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindow extends JPanel{

Image Menu;
String LogoSource = "Logo.png";

public MainWindow() {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(LogoSource));
    Menu = ii.getImage();
    Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();

        }
});
    timer.start();

}   

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(Menu, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null); 


    }
}
```

Code #2 (this creates the JFrame)

```
package com.mainwindow.draw;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame {

public Frame() {
    add(new MainWindow());
    setTitle("Game Inviroment Graphics Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(640, 480);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some kind of flag to determine if the image should be drawn or not and simply change it's state as needed...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (draw) {
        g2.drawImage(Menu, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null); 
    }
}
```

Then change the state of the flag when you need to...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        draw = false;
        repaint();
    }
});
```

Note: It's not recommended to to override `paint`, `paint` is at the top of the paint change and can easily break how the paint process works, causing no end of issues.  Instead, it's normally recommended to use `paintComponent` instead.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Also note: `javax.swing.Timer` expects the delay in milliseconds...5 is kind of fast...

Comment: Umm im getting this error: at com.mainwindow.draw.MainWindow.paintComponent(MainWindow.java:35)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's not much of an error message...Did you declare the `draw` variable before trying to use it?

Comment: Hehehe, opps.  Was calling `super.paint` instead of `super.paintComponent` :P